# How do I update SSRS 2012 tools in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got an issue with an SSRS 2012 report rendering differently between environments and I'm pretty sure that it is down to SSRS being at a different patch level. However, the one that works is on `11.0.2332` and the one that doesn't work is on `11.0.5058`. This is a problem as we don't want to downgrade the server upon which it doesn't work! My next thought was to see if the version of SSRS tools that I am using to edit the report might be on a patch level that produces a report that renders fine on `11.0.2332` but not on `11.0.5058`. To throw more spice into the mix, my tools are version `11.0.3402`! I get this from VS 2012 Help->About. I'd like to get those tools up the same level as the server upon which it isn't working (`11.0.5058`) in the hope that editing the report with the patched tools will make the report work on `11.0.5058`. I installed SQL Server SP2 on my dev box but this did not upgrade the tools. I haven't been able to find the relevant package that will do this upgrade. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it! https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843 - Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012